# Shadow layer work with the emulator but not on an actual device

Tags: android, paint, shadow

I'm creating a custom drawable (it extends from Drawable) and i'm trying to put a shadow effect on it.

Here's a part of my code :

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, Y/2);
    path.lineTo(X/2, Y);
    path.lineTo(X, Y/2);
    path.lineTo(X, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red_dark));
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2f);
    paint.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 10f, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

I don't know why but it put a shadow with the same color, i double checked everything and i don't see where the problem is. I test it on a galaxy nexus. But on the emulator it works just fine.

Comment: This works fine on mine Samsung Note, but I am extending a View not drawable. Have you tried this on more devices?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure, but this maybe because of hardware acceleration. `setShadowLayer` doen't work if view accelerated. Try to disable acceleration for whole app and check. [Read this.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

> Unsupported Drawing Operations
>
> setShadowLayer(): works with text only
>
> Use a software layer type to force a view to be rendered in software. If a view that is hardware accelerated (for instance, if your whole application is hardware acclerated), is having rendering problems, this is an easy way to work around limitations of the hardware rendering pipeline.

Use [setLayerType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) to set layer type to individual views or [turn off acceleration in your manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#hwaccel) for whole app.

Comment: It is indeed because of hardware acceleration. Drop shadows are currently only supported on text. If you need drop shadows on other shapes you should use a software layer on your view.

Comment: Ho, and how can i do that ? Because i'm not such a graphical developer.